# ASP.NET send email through 1and1 smtp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp

I am having issues sending an email through 1and1 smtp

Here is my code that i use in my asp.net mvc application: 
(When I used this code with gmail it works fine, but now I have to use 1and1 and it won't work :(

```
public void Send(Inquiry inquiry)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient ("Smtp.1and1.com", 587);
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail@mywebsite.com", "mypassword");

        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();


        mail.From = new MailAddress("sales@mywebsite.com", "myname");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("sales@mywebsite.com"));
        mail.Subject = $"New inquiry from {inquiry.Name}";
        mail.Body = $"{inquiry.Message}\r " +
            $"Recieved: {inquiry.Date}";
        mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(inquiry.Email));


        smtpClient.Send(mail);
    }
```

The error that I get is:

```
SmtpException: Error in processing. The server response was: Requested action aborted: local error in processing
```

System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, string response)

Comment: Can you send an e-mail with the same parameters from an e-mail client?

Comment: I used the same exact code to send from Gmail just changed server name. (does that clarify?)

Comment: It doesn't clarify anything, unless Gmail and 1and1 are using the exact same server software with the exact same configuration.

Comment: I'm especially interested to see if removing `ReplyToList` makes a difference, although confirming you can send the exact same e-mail (same from, same to, same subject, same body, same reply to, same credentials) from a regular mail client would be indicative of if the problem is your code or something else.

Comment: Thanks! (Do you know anything about 1and1? How to send with SMTP client through them?)

Comment: I did try removing 'ReplyToList' but it didn't make any difference. Thanks loads though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my changes and now it works!

Mail.from and mail.to were different addresses from the email used to login...

Here us the fixed code:

```
 public void Send(Inquiry inquiry)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient ("smtp.1and1.com",587);
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail@mywebsite.com", "mypassword");

        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        //Setting From , To and CC
        mail.From = new MailAddress("mail@mywebsite.com", "myname");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("mail@mywebsite.com"));
        mail.Subject = $"New inquiry from {inquiry.Name}";
        mail.Body = $"From: {inquiry.Name}\n" +
            $"Phone number: {inquiry.PhoneNumber} \n" +
            $"Message: {inquiry.Message}\n \n" +

            $"Recieved: {inquiry.Date}";
       mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(inquiry.Email));


        smtpClient.Send(mail);
    }
```

Comment: Interesting. I guess 1&1 are more strict than Google.

Answer (score 0):

From [1and1 error page](https://www.ionos.com/help/email-office/postmaster/smtp-error-messages-of-the-11-ionos-mail-servers/)

> **451 Requested action aborted: local error in processing:**
>
> The email could not be delivered successfully because the service was
>   temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.
>
> **Please note**: For emails to be delivered successfully, it is important,
>   among other things, that the resolution of the DNS query is always
>   answered quickly by the responsible DNS service. If problems persist,
>   you should therefore inform the administrator of the sender domain so
>   that he can ensure a fast name resolution.